I want to understand why this is a bad question.
I have a question that I think is valid. I've looked at the guide to write a good question and I'm still confused why it is a bad question.
I don't want an answer to the question but I do want to know why it is a bad question. Could someone list or summeraize the problems with the question.
What tools are known to help solve multi-variable modular arithmetic?

It was closed just over an hour ago and has to be reopened.

Even closed with my edits I'm still getting down votes. These down votes lead me to believe that I'm missing something else to make the question valid to be reopened.

Not that "being closed" is orthogonal to "is a bad question".  Not every good question is a good fit for this site.  The original version of the question was a simple "problem statement", without any real context.  The current version of the question, I think, is likely to remain closed, as we have far too much history on this site with Collatz (note the spelling) crankery---this really isn't the right place to try to crack open problems.

Ok, good to know that I should avoid talking about the Collatz (spelling noted) as a reason for my post. @XanderHenderson would you be able to expand on "... was a simple problem statement...", I think this is where I got it wrong. Should I have worded the problem differently, added multiple examples of the type of problem that I have come across, added examples of what I had attempted already to solve it?

@Tolure https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

@XanderHenderson Ok so after digging deeper through the comments of the "How to ask a good question" (Ctrl + F "Statement")  I fell on this post. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9180/proposal-ban-verbatim-homework-questions-which-have-no-accompanying-text. Because I should avoid posting about the Collatz Conjecture and because I need to provide context I now understand why my post and edits were not well received. (Honest Question) Are there any other topics similar to the Collatz Conjecture that I should avoid posting about on the Mathematics Exchange?

@Tolure In general, the community here is pretty hostile to questions which attempt to resolve famous open problems.  These include things like the twin prime conjecture, the Collatz conjecture, the Riemann hypothesis, and so on.

@XanderHenderson I'm having fun exploring the Collatz Conjecture I'm not trying to solve it. But I do understand.

@XanderHenderson thank you for letting me know about the other topics to avoide. If I may ask you, I have tried to reword the post to provide context while not mentioning the Collatz Conjecture, in your opinion do you think it should still remain closed?

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.
